# Can't keep the cell format in vba

Tags: vba, excel

i try to keep the same cell format in my vba script but i can't.

My variable prixB is always a 'number' and my variable prixA is a standard type. I need to have them in money like they are in the base document.

There's my script!

Thank you for your help

```
Sub Intersection()

Dim nombre As Integer
Dim tableauDate(1 To 115) As Date
Dim tableauValeur(1 To 115) As String
Dim valeur As Variant
Dim incrementeurForeach As Integer
Dim dateA As Date
Dim dateB As Date
Dim prixA As Currency
Dim prixB As Currency

nombre = 115
incrementeurForeach = 1

For incrementeur = 2 To nombre

dateA = Range("A" & incrementeur).Value
dateB = Range("c" & incrementeur).Value
prixA = Range("B" & incrementeur).Value
prixB = Range("D" & incrementeur).Value

Select Case dateA
    Case Is = dateB
        tableauDate(incrementeur) = dateA

    Case Is > dateB
        tableauDate(incrementeur) = dateA

    Case Else:
        tableauDate(incrementeur) = dateB

End Select

If prixA >= prixB Then
    tableauValeur(incrementeur) = prixA
Else
    tableauValeur(incrementeur) = prixB
End If

Next incrementeur


Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

For Each valeur In tableauDate

Range("A1").Offset(incrementeurForeach, 0).Value = tableauDate(incrementeurForeach)
Range("B1").Offset(incrementeurForeach, 0).Value = tableauValeur(incrementeurForeach)

incrementeurForeach = incrementeurForeach + 1

Next valeur

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this is very old, however I believe i have your solution. Using the .Text vs .Value returns the cells actual text, not its contents. I ran into this as i wanted my vba code to include the "$" symbol, as well as the correct formatting when sending totals for a mortgage company. Hopefully this will help someone out there haha :)

`dateA = Range("A" & incrementeur).text
dateB = Range("c" & incrementeur).text
prixA = Range("B" & incrementeur).text
prixB = Range("D" & incrementeur).text`

Answer (score 0):

To apply number formatting (and that's all it is in Excel) you can just:

`Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#"` or `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#.##"`, etc.

You may modify the number format as needed for your specific currency, decimal precision, etc.

Comment: When I do it, a column of "0" appears.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean. In any case, the solution will be to apply a `.NumberFormat`.  Please try recording a macro, manually changing the number format of one or two cells to the desired format, and then posting the resulting code from the macro recorder. I will modify my solution per your response.